# Выполнить UPDATE REPLACE к большой таблице

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

Нужно выполнить sql запрос к таблице на 85 миллионов строк (6.8 гб, 4 колонки, колонка id в индексе).

```
UPDATE Detailinfo
SET id=REPLACE(id,'"','')
```

Вываливается с ошибкой (1206): The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size */

Если снять индекс и попытаться выполнить запрос без него, то mysql просто повисает.

БД находится на локалке, так что вопрос временной остановки работоспособности не волнует.

Можно как-то порезать запрос на порции?

Comment: а если порциями обновлять и условие добавить? чтобы лишние записи не выбирались и обновлялись кусками, т.е. делаем что-то типа `UPDATE... WHERE id like '%"%' LIMIT 0, 1000`

Comment: как подсказывает англ. стак можно еще через LOCK/UNLOCK TABLES попробовать, оно должно отключать построчный лок, на котором и вываливается ошибка

Comment: Проблема с лок/анлок не решится. Так запрос повисает даже без индекса. Решение с `WHERE` уже пробовал, повисает все равно. Ощущение, что `WHERE` выполняет не первым. p.s. Хотя без `UPDATE` находит всего 80к строк, в которых и нужно сделать `REPLACE`.

Comment: Зачем UPDATE 100% таблицы? WHERE id like '%"%'  обязательно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Хотя без UPDATE находит всего 80к строк, в которых и нужно сделать REPLACE

Тогда не вижу проблемы, если у вас локальная БД.
Сделайте запрос вида:

```
SELECT CONCAT('UP DATE Detailinfo SET Id=''',REPLACE(Id, '"', '') 
  ,'''WHERE Id=''',Id,'''')
FROM Detailinfo
WHERE name LIKE '%"%'
```

Получите 80 строк вида:

```
UPDATE Detailinfo SET Id='jennifer lopez'WHERE Id='""jennifer lopez""'
UPDATE Detailinfo SET Id='ray liotta'WHERE Id='"ray" "liotta"'
UPDATE Detailinfo SET Id='samuel l. jackson'WHERE Id='"samuel" l. "jackson"'
```

Потом их скопируйте и запустите.

Скорее всего, если там всего 80 строк, можно аккуратно UPDATE с WHERE написать, но это нужно на реальных данных смотреть, чем серверу не нравится простой UPDATE с WHERE.

**UPD:** стоп. 80к строк? Тогда немного не подойдёт:)

> Можно как-то порезать запрос на порции?

Попробуйте выполнить такой запрос:

```
SELECT CONCAT(''
  ,'UP DATE Detailinfo SET Id=REPLACE(Id, ''"'', '''')'
  ,'WHERE Id BETWEEN ''', MIN(Id), ''' AND ''', MAX(Id)
  ,''' AND Id LIKE ''%"%'''
)QRY
FROM(
  SELECT Id, @I := @I+1 AS N
  ,1000000 AS K --тут задайте нужное значение K
  FROM Detailinfo, (SELECT @I := -1)I
  ORDER BY Id
)T
GROUP BY N-N%K
```

Он вернёт вам 850 dml запросов на UPDATE вида:

```
UPDATE Detailinfo SET Id=REPLACE(Id, '"', '')WHERE Id BETWEEN 'alan rickman' AND 'gary oldman' AND Id LIKE '%"%'
UPDATE Detailinfo SET Id=REPLACE(Id, '"', '')WHERE Id BETWEEN 'george clooney' AND 'michael caine' AND Id LIKE '%"%'
UPDATE Detailinfo SET Id=REPLACE(Id, '"', '')WHERE Id BETWEEN 'michael douglas' AND 'steve martin' AND Id LIKE '%"%'
UPDATE Detailinfo SET Id=REPLACE(Id, '"', '')WHERE Id BETWEEN 'sylvester stallone' AND 'tommy lee jones' AND Id LIKE '%"%'
```

Каждый из которых будет обрабатывать пачку из 1млн. строк, размер пачки можно изменить, задавая параметр K в запросе.

Как он работает: сортирует все строки в порядке Id, нумерует. Потом группирует каждую пачку(K штук), находит минимальное и максимальное значение Id, и генерит соотв. DML запрос.

Так как по Id есть индекс, должен нормально выполнится. Если поставить К=10млн. получим 85 DML запросов.

Comment: Можно ещё вставить ваши 50к строк в промежуточную табличку с полями `tempTable(Id INT, IdForUpdate строка)` и потом писать запросы типа таких `update Detailinfo set .... where id in (select idForUpdate from tempTable where id between 1 and 10000)` - тоже разделение по пачкам

Comment: Запрос с DML тоже повис. Решил задачу, выполнив `INSERT` с `WHERE id like '%"%'` в отдельную таблицу, там сделав `REPLACE`, а затем обратный `INSERT` в начальную таблицу. Правда, теперь надо как-то выполнить `DELETE` лишних строк (он тоже повисает), но результат пока устраивает.

Comment: @Mike Использовал `LOCK` для `DELTE`:
`LOCK TABLES Detailinfo WRITE;
DELETE FROM Detailinfo WHERE id like '%"%';
UNLOCK TABLES Detailinfo;`

Вывалилось опять же с 1206 ошибкой. Процессы лишние висеть не могут, после таких выкрутасов с БД, приходится быстренько перегрузить Open Server (а с ним и все процессы соответственно)

Comment: @Zhenya40 Кстати, а обычный select с тем же условием, что вы даете для delete по скорости нормально работает. попробуйте тот же select но с limit небольшим. потом обратите внимание, что delete то же позволяет задавать limit. Т.е. вы спокойно можете удалять по 1000 строк скажем

Answer (score 1):

Пишут, что при невозможности использовать индексы, MySQL может лочить все записи, которые сканирует.

Проблема возникает из-за недостаточного размера настройки `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. Так что, если ограничения через WHERE или LIMIT вас не спасают, вы можете попробовать изменить этот параметр.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/10253482/272885